# Mongo $all Queries Using Selective Query

Tags: mongodb

The Mongo [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) comment on the `$all` operator.

> In the current release queries that use the $all operator must scan
>   all the documents that match the first element in the query array. As
>   a result, even with an index to support the query, the operation may
>   be long running, particularly when the first element in the array is
>   not very selective.

Given my DB structure (shown below), I am thinking of how to ensure that, whenever I make an `$all` query using a Mongo API, the first argument will be the `more selective` field.

```
{ 
 _id: 1,
 records : [ {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"}, {n: "Age", v: 100} ]
}
```

My first thought was to, periodically, create a dynamic list of "selective" query fields. When performing a query in code, I'd look at the 2+ fields being searched via the `$all` operator, and then put the more/most "selective" item as the first element.

Is there a better way or a best practice for handling this subject?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "more selective". Can you update your question with 3 documents and a typical query (in english).

Comment: Can your document structure be changed ? Searching (and inserting) would be much simpler and efficient if you could.

Comment: @ixe013 - I structured my database in the above format as per Antoine Girbal's post - http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use. Here are examples to show `non-selective` queries. Assume I have `1,000,000` documents in my collection. 900,000 have the name "Kevin." The documents' ages are roughly random. As a result, performing a query (using $all and $elemMatch) to match on a particular name and age will be much **faster** if age is the first argument in the query.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that selectivity depends on the key *and* the value. Moreover, one could use more complex expressions such as `$elemMatch` and `$gte`. So whether the cost used to maintain the list of more 'selective' indexes amortizes depends on the very details of query patterns, spread in values, r/w ratio, etc. To truly gain efficiency, you'd have to know meta information, e.g. let's say an integer field is widely distributed. Then `$gt:50` and `$gt:60` will have the same selectivity. If it's a normal distribution around 50 though, `$gt:60` will be a lot more selective...

Comment: starting with 2.6 the query optimizer will pick the correct use of index more effectively, including using index self-intersection, so this optimization would no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your DB structure is limited to a few fields, I think the best (and easy) option is to change the DB structure from

```
{ 
 _id: 1,
 records : [ {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"}, {n: "Age", v: 100} ]
}
```

to

```
{ 
 _id: 1,
 Name: "Kevin",
 Age: 100
}
```

So that you can query your db on an index on {Name: 1, Age: 1}

***BUT***, if the "records" array has a generic key/value structure **and you have to use the $all operator**, than you can use the aggregation framework (or MapReduce) to build a dynamic list of "selective" query fields.

I'll explain my thought with an example (with only a sample of coding):

Maybe your query is of this kind:

```
db.structure.find({ records: { 
    $all: [ {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"}, {n: "Age", v: 100} ] 
} } )
```

And for example

```
db.structure.find({ 
    records: {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"} 
} ).count() --> 1000

db.structure.find({ 
    records: {n: "Age", v: 100} 
} ).count() --> 100   // -> most selective!
```

So, the fastest query will be with {n: "Age", v: 100} as first item...

You can write a batch with something like

```
var result = db.structure.aggregate([
 { $unwind: "records" },
 { $group: {
     _id: "$records",
     record_count: { $sum: 1 }
   }
 }
]);
db.selective_items.save(result.result);
```

Then, when you want to query with the $all operator, you need first of all to query selective_items collection and find the record with the lower value of record_count, and then build the $all query with the right first element.

I hope that this solution answers your question

Answer (score 1):

The problem with keeping track of "selective" attributes is it requires constant re-sampling of data.  Plus it assumes that every attribute that's selective will retain that property no matter what value is being provided to the query.

Here's an example of a set of possible attributes:

```
{ n:"lastName", v:"Kamsky" }    vs.   { n:"lastName", v:"Smith" }

{ n:"firstName", v:"Asya" }     vs.   { n:"firstName", v:"Jessica" }

{ n:"Age", v: 21 }              vs.   { n:"Age", v: 15 }
```

On the first two comparison lines, last name and first name can be either very selective (when the first or last name is rare) or not particularly selective (when it's common across the population of your database).

On the third line, we can't tell whether either of the "Age" values is going to be selective if we don't know what the contents of the database are.  If it's a collection of college students you are querying then the second value will end up being extremely selective, but if it's high school students then the first value will be the highly selective one.

If any of your queries are inequalities then I would say they won't make for a good first position element, unless none of the other elements are selective.

But how can you track what is and isn't selective?

Here is something you can do to track "statistics" (so to speak):

```
var X = 3;  // assign a threshold equal to some number that's "too high" to scan 
db.<collection>.aggregate( 
     {$unwind  :  "$records"}, 
     {$group   :  {_id:{n:"$records.n",v:"$records.v"}, count:{$sum:1}}}, 
     {$group   :  {_id:"$_id.n", totalDistinctValues:{$sum:1}, values:{$push:{value:"$_id.v", appears:"$count"}} } },
     {$project :  {_id:0, AttributeName:"$_id", totalDistinctValues:1, values:1}}, 
     {$match   :  {"values.appears":{$not:{$gte: X }} }}, 
     {$sort    :  {totalDistinctValues:1}}, 
     {$limit   :  10}
)
```

The above aggregation will return the ten attributes which have the most unique (distinct) values.  In addition each document will include the list of possible values and how many times it appears.  There is a lot of room to tweak this, depending on your exact fields and likely data distribution - you can certainly save this out to a collection to query but I would simply cache this in the application as this is not something that it makes sense to persist in the use case you described.

On my small test collection the result returned is this (I also had "Employers" field but half the records listed the same employer so that eliminated it):

```
[
    {
        "totalDistinctValues" : 5,
        "AttributeName" : "firstName",
        "values" : [
            {
                "value" : "Sheldon",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Raj",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Penny",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Asya",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "John",
                "appears" : 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "totalDistinctValues" : 6,
        "AttributeName" : "lastName",
        "values" : [
            {
                "value" : "Kumar",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Smith",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Lane",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Williams",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Kamsky",
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : "Cooper",
                "appears" : 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "totalDistinctValues" : 6,
        "AttributeName" : "Age",
        "values" : [
            {
                "value" : 31,
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : 21,
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : 22,
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : 29,
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : 49,
                "appears" : 1
            },
            {
                "value" : 59,
                "appears" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Bottom line: once you run this aggregation and take a look at the real distribution in your data, it may become obvious that some attributes are naturally selective and will always (or frequently) be present in queries.  Put those first.  Otherwise, use the stats to dynamically place the more selective attribute first and vote on https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2348 which is tracking improvements in index use for such queries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [blog post](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use), it walks through some of the considerations when using a generic structure such as the one you're showing above. In general, the selectivity condition will affect you differently because each condition inside of $all will be for the same field. Another thing to consider is using the [explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) operator on your queries to see which ones perform better, etc.

Comment: Hi crcsmnky - understood on using the `explain` on my `find` queries. However, is my programmatic approach of holding a map of selective fields the way to go? In my testing with 5 million documents where I've performed an exact matching `find ($all {elemMatch1}, {elemMatch2}}`, where, switching the elemMatch terms (1 and 2) varies the speed of the query from 700 ms to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: 
I think $all will always perform slowly as mentioned in MongoDB docs. One thing to consider when using MongoDB is the query should always try to reduce your projection to the lowest form and then work on the remaining data.
Any array operations will highly benefit from adding another criteria in the find query.

That being said, since $all should internally check all the elements and even if the individual values are index it still has m*n combinations. Technically, order should not matter but I guess it does.

Always try to avoid $all, $nin, $ne operations. Its true even in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index defined on the array field, running several counts on the field values will be faster than the bad order in the $all phase. However this sound extreme suboptimal not this is the case, so they will use the index to determine the selectivity (num of elements). This allows more advanced application design while you can run fully parallel the count queries, so they can run in different threads in the very same time. Would be more optimal to run [index covered queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries) but unfortunately it is not supported on array fields.

If there is lack of resources (lots of user requests, and big number of elements in the $all array) I would not try to optimize to the best the query always, in this case if you have several elements in the  $all array i would choose always at maximum 3 as a reasonable amount to check, and choose the best among those. Or would define some acceptable values for example if the first 3 parallel count return less than a  200 documents i would accept it as a first element in an $all array. Of course it depends on if you have to deal with lots of concurrent user requests or just some (few requests to be optimized for low latency will enable you to prepare and run several count queries at once without the risk to stress down the db).